# Do Proxies Completely Mask Your Traffic?

Tags: proxy, socks5

If you route both your upload and downloads through a proxy can your ISP or "prying eyes" still see what your traffic is?

Does the proxy encrypt the traffic in a way so that it is not decipherable?

I'm using a Socks5 proxy with Auth.

Comment: First it depends on if they encrypt.  Then do they use a method that is actually secure, as research are find more and more techniques are weak to one attack or another.  Third, is the library/software they use implement the encryption coded properly.  ISP probably have enough resources to brute force it, do a MITM, or capture your encryption keys in transit.  It does make it more difficult.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No,  a proxy proxies your traffic but does not neccessarily (or usually) encrypt it.

If anything, a proxy makes it easier for prying eyes to sniff traffic, as it is handled by an application which can be designed to log requests and do anything else it requires.

Also, very often, proxy servers will add an "X-FORWARDED-FOR" header to requests, so not only can the address of the proxy be obtained, but the original IP address is often passed on through this header.